# Smaller scale Java distributed programming

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, hadoop, distributed-computing

I'm learning a bit more about hadoop and its applications, and I understand it is geared toward massive datasets and large files. Let's say I had an application in which I was processing a relatively small number of files (say 100k), which isn't a huge number for something like hadoop/hdfs. However, it does take a macro amount of time to run on a single machine, so I'd like to distribute the process.

The problem can be broken down into a map reduce style problem (e.g. each of the files can be processed independently and then I can aggregate the results). I'm open to using infrastructure such as Amazon EC2, but I'm not so sure about what technologies to be exploring for actually aggregating the results of the process. Seems like hadoop might be a bit overkill here.

Can anyone provide guidance on this type of problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Hadoop's reduce phase is meant exactly to aggregate the results of the computation.

Comment: Right, but isn't using hdfs, where a file size should be larger a little overkill when I have a bunch of small files (and I know there are techniques for aggregating those files though, and in my case, the files are distinct files, such as images). I guess if hdfs isn't appropriate I could always use something like s3?

Comment: You're right, HDFS was not meant for a large amount of small files and the performance is very poor, I can tell you this from my own experiments with a university "cluster". Fortunately my files were text files, so merging them into a single large file was possible and it improved the performance by 60x I think. :)

Comment: So I'm not sure if aggregating the files into larger files is the right approach here, or if there might be alternative frameworks that would be more suitable.

Comment: The problem is that this limitation is tightly linked with the fact that hard disks are mechanical and so the head needs to seek the next read location every time you jump to a new file and this operation is expensive. This is why reading a single file sequentially is much faster.

Comment: Right, so I could use a sequencefile if needed, but I didn't know if there were frameworks that were more appropriate given that it's not a huge dataset.

Comment: Do the small files fit into RAM?

Comment: Not all at once, but individual ones could

Comment: Akka (http://akka.io/) is a java distributed programming framework that can be used in map-reduce fashion for parallel programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you may want to reconsider your assumption that you can't combine files.  Even images can be combined- you just need to figure out how to do that in a way that allows you to break them out again in your mappers.  Combining them with some sort of sentinel value or magic number between them might make it possible to turn them into one giant file.

Other options include HBase, where you could store the images in cells.  HBase also has a built-in TableMapper and TableReducer, and can store the results of your processing alongside the raw data in a semi-structured way.

EDIT: As for the "is Hadoop overkill" question, you need to consider the following:

1. Hadoop adds at least one machine of overhead (the HDFS NameNode).  You typically dont want to store data or run jobs on that machine, since it is a SPOF.
2. Hadoop is best suited for processing data in batch, with relatively high latency.  As @Raihan mentions, there are several other FOSS distributed compute architectures that may server your needs better if you need realtime or low-latency results.
3. 100k files isn't so very few.  Even if they are 100k each, that's 10GB of data.
4. Other than the above, Hadoop is a relatively low-overhead way of approaching distributed computing problems.  It has a huge, helpful community behind it, so you can get help quickly if you need it.  And it is focused on running on cheap hardware and a free OS, so there really isnt any significant overhead.

In short, I'd try it before you discard it for something else.

Comment: what I meant was I couldn't combine them into a single file that could be processed all at once. I could put them into an archive or possibly a hadoop sequence file. I should have been more clear about that. The main issue in the question was more about is hadoop a bit overkill for such a relatively small number of files?